# Debugging not working in Visual Studio Code with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm fairly new to python and to date I've been using Komodo as my interpreter.  I decided to try something more robust, so I installed Visual Studio Code version 1.23.1 and I'm running Python 3.6.4.  When I run a basic script it runs properly, but I noticed in the debugger window none of the variables appear, in fact nothing appears.  Not sure what I've done wrong.  The debug is set to DEBUE Python: Current File.

Answer (score 4):

By default VSCode's debugger will execute your file until it either encounters a breakpoint (or exception) or your program exits. To change this behavior, set `"stopOnEntry": true` your `launch.json` configuration like so:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            // Add this line
            "stopOnEntry": true
        },
        // other configurations
        ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! I swill make this change and see how it goes.

Comment: When I click F1 > Debug open launch.json > Select Environment - there is no python option, but node, chrome, edge.. Python is installed in c:/python, in the path and the python debugger extension also.